# Javascript using parameter on an object

Tags: javascript, object

after a bit of guidance here as i think i'm getting myself confused ;)

I have an object, an example below:

```
{
  "_id": "63dd35e801ad6ada9a5eeb08",
  "name": "Joe Bloggs",
  "technicalCertification": true,
  "salesCertification": true,
  "salesCertificationExpiry": "2023-12-27T12:02:31.043Z",
  "techicalCertificationExpiry": "2024-09-29T12:02:48.254Z"
}
```

There may be more fields with the ISO date format, so to display this in a friendly manner i was trying to create a function such as:

```
const formatISODate = function (obj, field) {
  let day = obj.data[field].split('T')[0].split('-')[2]
  let month = obj.data[field].split('T')[0].split('-')[1]
  let year = obj.data[field].split('T')[0].split('-')[0]

  return `${day} ${month} ${year}`
}
```

which takes in the object and the name of the field i want to format like formatISODate(obj, 'salesCertificationExpiry')

So my question is:

1. is there an easy way to do this (am i making it more complex than it has to be)
2. i can't seem to reference the field parameter (i get 'obj.data[field].split' is not a function) nor can i get the value of the field with the matching parameter.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be great, as i think it's nearly there.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: also, it's likely because you are using obj.data[field]. try using obj[field]

Comment: I tested your function and it works... assuming the object being passed had "data" in it. So it really comes down to the object itself.

Comment: ThisGuy, thanks - i was so close, but i was calling a "field" with a spelling mistake in it, so the field did not exist in the object.

imvain2 - thanks for the test and confirmation it was working, still getting used to it all, so nice to have some confirmation.

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find year, month and day with a regexp, and reduce right:

```js
const formatISODate = (obj, field) => obj.data[field].match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/).reduceRight((r, p, i) => i > 0 ? r + ' ' + p : r);
console.log(formatISODate(obj, 'techicalCertificationExpiry'));
```

```html
<script>
const obj = {data: {
  "_id": "63dd35e801ad6ada9a5eeb08",
  "name": "Joe Bloggs",
  "technicalCertification": true,
  "salesCertification": true,
  "salesCertificationExpiry": "2023-12-27T12:02:31.043Z",
  "techicalCertificationExpiry": "2024-09-29T12:02:48.254Z"
}};
</script>
```

Benchmark different solutions:

```
` Cycles: 1000000 / Chrome/117
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
regex + reduceRight              1.0x  |   62   63   68   69   75   77   79
split + reduceRight              1.6x  |   97   98   99   99  102  109  109
regex + slice + reverse + join   1.6x  |  100  104  105  105  107  108  108
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script benchmark="1000000">

const date = '2024-09-29T12:02:48.254Z';

// @benchmark regex + slice + reverse + join
date.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/).slice(1).reverse().join(' ');

// @benchmark regex + reduceRight
date.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/).reduceRight((r, p, i) => i > 0 ? r + ' ' + p : r);

// @benchmark split + reduceRight
date.slice(0, 10).split('-').reduceRight((r, p) => r + ' ' + p);

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for this - lots more things for me to try - i'm not going to just copy and paste these, but try each of them and learn from it. 

thankyou for helping me in learning.

Jason

Answer (score 1):

```
const formatISODate = function (obj, field) {
  let baseDate = obj[field].split('T')[0].split('-');
  return `${baseDate[2]} ${baseDate[1]} ${baseDate[0]}`;
}
```

Can try this with the code reusability !!

Comment: Thanks Gopi - always like to improve reusability, so this helps.

Comment: Drop an upvote , if u would like to !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const formatISODate = function (obj, field) {
  let day = obj[field].split('T')[0].split('-')[2]
  let month = obj[field].split('T')[0].split('-')[1]
  let year = obj[field].split('T')[0].split('-')[0]

  return `${day} ${month} ${year}`
}
```